# Division with float result (homework)

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

i am currently kinda stuck at my homework and kindly asking for some assistance. Our task is to implement x^4 / 4! in arm assembly. I have successfully calculated the right values for x^4 and 4!, but i am stuck at how to calculate the division wich has obviously a floating point as result. I already implemented a simple division algorithm with some help, but for my understanding this is only for integer division, isn't it?

```
 CMP             R2, #0
 BEQ divide_end


 MOV      R0,#0     ;clear R0 to accumulate result
 MOV      R3,#1     ;set bit 0 in R3, which will be
                    ;shifted left then right
.start
 CMP      R2,R1
 MOVLS    R2,R2,LSL#1
 MOVLS    R3,R3,LSL#1
 BLS      start
 ;shift R2 left until it is about to
 ;be bigger than R1
 ;shift R3 left in parallel in order
 ;to flag how far we have to go

.next
 CMP       R1,R2      ;carry set if R1>R2
 SUBCS     R1,R1,R2   ;subtract R2 from R1 if this would
                      ;give a positive answer
 ADDCS     R0,R0,R3   ;and add the current bit in R3 to
                      ;the accumulating answer in R0

 MOVS      R3,R3,LSR#1     ;Shift R3 right into carry flag
 MOVCC     R2,R2,LSR#1     ;and if bit 0 of R3 was zero, also
                           ;shift R2 right
 BCC       next            ;If carry not clear, R3 has shifted
                           ;back to where it started, and we
                           ;can end

.divide_end
```

Maybe i am just really dumb here, but any help would be appreciated
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you not just use the floating-point instructions?

Comment: You mean by converting the two integers to floating points and then use VDIV? I was not quite sure if this was the right way to do it. Can i use the r0-r15 for this, or do i have to use the S registers?

Comment: It's not at all obvious that the result must be a floating-point value. Integer division is a reasonable choice, as is fixed-point division. Does the problem statement require floating-point?

Comment: We are allowed to use all FPU instructions. So i guess we should also use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just dumb. We were allowed to use the FPU instructions. So i could use VDIV!